# A simple explanation for the product topology?

Tags: general-topology

Nearly every definition of the product topology is too "greek symbolish" for me to understand. So could someone explain it in simple terms, preferably how we get the $R \times R $ from two $ R's $ in the standard topology.? I mean what is the principle behind choosing sets of a certain kind in $R \times R $ versus others in being the open sets?

Comment: Have you seen the basis of the product topology?

Comment: No.. I have a basic idea of what the basis is .

Comment: One way of viewing it is that it's the topology of pointwise convergence. $\qquad$

Comment: The conventional basic open sets of $\Bbb R$ are open intervals, and the corresponding basic open sets of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ are open rectangles (cartesian products of open intervals). Every open set in $\Bbb R$ is a union of open intervals, and every open set in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ is a union of open rectangles (even if the open set looks curved, like a ball). Make sense?

Comment: @arctictern Yes. But could you clarify your last line , 'even if they look curved' ?

Comment: Well, that's the idea. Given bases $B$ and $C$ for topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, a basis for $X\times Y$ is given by $\{b\times c:b\in B,c\in C\}$. In particular this works when $B$ and $C$ are the actual topologies (meaning the whole collections of all open sets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively). (More needs to be said if one is taking the direct product of infinitely many topological spaces.)

Comment: If you have familiarity with what a topology generated by collection of functions is, the product topology is the topology generated by the projections onto the coordinates.

Comment: Do you only care for two factors or finite products or also for infinite ones?

Comment: @quid Both actually.

Comment: Do you need help with the Greek alphabet and its use in mathematics? If so, please ask a specific question about that. Vague phrases like "too greek symbolish" don't help anyone to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_1:R\times R\to R$ and $p_2:R\times R\to R$ be the projections of $R\times R\; $ to, respectively, the first  and second  co-ordinates.

Let $S$ be the set of all topologies on $R \times R$ for which $p_1$ and $p_2$ are continuous.

Let $T$ be any member of $S.$ If $U$ is an open subset of $R$ then $p_1^{-1}U=U\times R \in T.$ And if $V$ is an open subset of $R$ then  $p_2^{-1}V=R\times V \in T.$ Hence if $U,V$ are open subsets of $R$ then $U\times V=(U\times R)\cap (R\times V) \in T.$ So  the set $B=\{U\times V: U,V$ open in $R\}$ is a subset of $T.$

$\bullet\;$ $\;B$ is a base for a unique  topology $T^*$ on $R\times R.$

So $T\supset T^*$ for every $T\in S.$ Observe also that $T^*\in S$ (Because for $U,V$ open in $R$ we have $p_1^{-1}U=U\times R\in B\subset T^*$  and $p_2^{-1}V=R\times V\in B\subset  T^*.$)

So $T^*$ is the common intersection of all the members of $S,$ and $T^*\in S.$ So $T^*$ is the weakest topology on $R\times R$ for which $p_1$ and $p_2$ are continuous. The Tychonoff product topology on $R\times R$ is defined to be be the weakest topology on $R\times R$ for which  $p_1$ and $p_2$ are continuous. So $T^*$ is the product topology.

Remark: If first sentence of the above paragraph is unclear, consider that $\forall T\in S\;(T^*\subset T)\implies T^*\subset \cap S,$ and that $T^*\in S\implies \cap S\subset T^*.$ So we have $T^*\subset \cap S\subset T^*.$

In terms of metrics, with the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ on $R,$ we may use it to define various metrics on $R^2 .$ For example  $d_1((x,y),(x',y'))=\max (|x-x'|,y-y'|), $ and $d_2((x,y),(x',y'))=|x-x'|+|y-y'|, $ and $d_3((x,y),(x',y'))=\sqrt {(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}.\; $  The metrics $ d_1,d_2,d_3 $ are all topologically equivalent : Each generates the product topology on $R^2.$